# example of Collapsible Panel inside GridView in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, collapsiblepanelextender

Hi I want to create GridView in which  Header Panel shows Partial Detail and then complete detail will be shown when click on that panel...

so give me example of it

Comment: I think if you thought about search the web you would have found results in the first page, always try to search first, you would gain tremendous amount of knowledge just because of searching on web